# Remove a single line from PDF with saving file's layout and styles

Tags: python, pdf

Is it possible to remove a single line at the end of the PDF using Python, but save the layout and styles of the page?

Assume I have a file with such a page like on the screenshot. I need to find and remove a certain line. The line is always the same and always placed on the last page of the document but documents themselves can have different number of lines at the last page.

Note: the example of the document is not an actual document to be modified, it is provided only for problem explanation.

[Page exapmle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3JXM.png)

Comment: You're wanting to remove the citation?

Comment: There are various PDF libraries for Python. Have a search, see what you find, try it out. If you have difficulty search [so], and if, there aren't solutions, ask a more precise [tag:python] question.

Comment: I searched [so] and found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346942/how-to-replace-delete-text-from-a-pdf-using-python